# CodeIgniter Login not working for Tablets and Phones

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, mobile

I have an Issue with tablets and phones logging into their accounts. Everything works fine on a desktop or laptop, It also works cross-browser(tested in Firefox, Chrome, Safari, and Internet Explorer.) However when I try to log on with a mobile device it does not work.

Here is the Site:
http://www.showtheapples.com/

Info:
This is a practice website I am still learning CodeIgniter.

My devices I am using:

HP Dell with Intel processor.(Working Fine)

Nokia Lumia 521 Windows Phone 8 (Internet Explorer for phones)

LG Motion LG-MS770 (Android Default Browser)

Lenovo IdeaTAB A-1000L Tablet  (Android Default Browser)

Windows Surface RT (Internet Explorer for RT)

I was told that it is a session Issue so I have tried playing around with these already:

```
 $config['sess_cookie_name']        = 'ci_session'; 
 $config['sess_expiration']      = 84200;
 $config['sess_expire_on_close']     = FALSE;
 $config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = FALSE;
 $config['sess_use_database']       = FALSE;
 $config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';
 $config['sess_match_ip']            = FALSE;
 $config['sess_match_useragent']    = FALSE;
 $config['sess_time_to_update']  = 300;
```

So far no Luck, The Users still however, get registered and are in the database, I have checked to see if they are actually there. They just cannot log in on a mobile device. Is there a fix for this? So far on the internet I have found no fixes.

I am Using CodeIgniter v 2.1.4 (Current Version)

Please If You guys can test this out with putting your email and a dummy password and find this issue. There are no tricks on the website. It simply asks you put in an email and create a password, you then recieve an email to activate your account.

If not and you can find the answer some other way it doesn't matter I will glady take it! Thank you all in advance.

Comment: I know this is off-topic but that slideshow is very intense on the eyes. Made me want to leave rather than poke around. Just 2 cents...

Comment: Yes, I do agree, the website is definitely not at all where it needs to be, I just have alot of dummy text and pictures just trying to get used to working with CodeIgniter, height and width adjustements, scaling and refining, along with a more responsive touch needs to be done and will be once I get the wire of the site done. Thank you for the positive feedback!

Answer (score 1):

You can resolve this problem by changing your mobile browser Cookies Settings to 'Allow'.

Comment: This is a vague answer. It is best as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
$config['sess_expiration']  =   6000;
```

The session expiration is too big (84200).
Replace 84200 with 6000 or less then check again.

Comment: I'm with same problem. It all works fine on computers. Your answer didn't helped. And theres no message error, nothing. It simply log's in and log's out back to login page.